# How do I give a Font Awesome 5 icon a background color? like star

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have used stars font awesome icons in which the first two stars have a yellow color, and the last two stars have a gray color and the middle star has two colors yellow and I want to make another half to be a gray color.

How do I make this?

see the snippet to understand

```css
.star-full-color{
  color: #FFB319 !important;
}
.star-no-color{
  color: #EEEEEE !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fas fa-star star-full-color"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star star-full-color"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star-half star-full-color"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star star-no-color"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star star-no-color"></i>
```

Comment: @j08691 - OP wants to specify two colors for the half-star, the linked question doesn't.

Comment: @galdin The same technique applies. If you need me to create a jsFiddle exampe for you let me know

Comment: @j08691 sure I'd love to see one if you don't mind. Thanks! I was only able to get this working with 6 elements (one placed over the other to make it look like a half star with two colors) rather than with just 5 elements.

Comment: @galdin https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7s035bpw/1/

Comment: Without changing the original markup: you can use :after to put another star behind the original star and color it to match a blank star. https://jsfiddle.net/r798b01o/

Comment: The final vote to re-open was done by me, sorry on behalf of the community that the closer did not read and understand this question was different from the question it was marked as a duplicate, pops to community members who highlighted than in the comments, made the vote lots easier :D